# Enable GTK3 Theming on Wine

Tags: wine

[Wine has an option for GTK theming](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278423/how-to-enable-gtk-theming-wine-staging-in-playonlinux) if you use the wine-staging version.

I've installed GTK3 on macOS through:

```
brew install gtk+3
```

However, the option remains disabled. Is there a way this can be done on macOS?

[image: Enable GTK3 Theming box disabled]

Answer (score 1):

As I’d said on Winehq, the only way to enable gtk themes required that wine-staging is built from source with this library available.

As you didn’t provide the version of macOS your running there’s little more information that can be provided, also from what was posted on Winehq you seem reluctant to compile wine from source making this impossible to achieve.

Comment: I understand, but as an open question, the specifics to my case are not important. I just don't find this has enough information online on how to proceed to grant this as the answer to the problem.

Comment: As I’ve said you need to compile wine-staging from source with gtk3 available. If you need a more in-depth guide for compiling wine from source I could provide one.